Exercise 4.2 in Stochastic Calculus for Finance 2
I am going through the exercises in chapter 4 of Steven E. Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance 2 and I can't get through exercise 4.2 i). In short, we must show that
$$\sum_{j=l}^k \Delta_{t_j}(W_{t_{j+1}} - W_{t_j})$$
is independent of $\mathcal{F_{t_l}}$, where $W_t$ is a Brownian motion and $\mathcal{F}_t$ is its associated filtration. Also, $\Delta_{t_j}$ is non-random. My strategy is to use the fact that the increment that each increment of brownian motion $(W_{t_{j+1}} - W_{t_j})$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{t_j}$, and thus independent of $\mathcal{F}_{t_l}$. Then I would like to use the following fact:
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables independent of $\mathcal{A}$ and let $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $cX$ and $X+Y$ are independent of $\mathcal{A}$.
But, a comment asserts this is simply not true. I do not know how to proceed in this case.

This is false. $X+Y$ need not be independent of $\mathcal A$.

Hi: By independent increments of $W_{t_{j}}$, $(W_{t_{j+1}} - W_{t_j})$ is independent of $F_{l}$ for $ l \le j$.  $\Delta_{t_{j}}$ doesn't play a role because it's a known constant.

"$\Delta_{t_j}$ doesn't play a role", that would be part of the fact I want to verify, and I would still need the other part about the indepence of $X+Y$ wrt $\mathcal{A}$ to prove the exercise.
